# Try to implement ''all' with ''any'' in haskell List

Tags: java, list, haskell

I'm trying to implement the ''all'' function with ''any'', but i'm getting an error.
My code:

```hs
all''' ::  (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all''' p xs = not (any''' not (p) xs)
```

The java code which is from a book and working:

```java
public boolean forAll(Function<A, Boolean> p) {
return !exists(x -> !p.apply(x));
}
```

My error:

[image]

I hope someone can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: `not (p)` -> `(not . p)` (or `(\x -> not (p x))`)

Comment: Your java code most directly corresponds to the Haskell code `all''' p = not (any''' (\x -> not (p x)))`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, or links to pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function application syntax in Haskell is not the same as in Java. In Haskell, you apply a function by just putting it next to an argument:

```hs
f x  -- The function f applied to x
```

Function application associates to the left, so when you wrote

```hs
not (any''' not (p) xs)
```

the compiler read that as applying `any'''` to the function `not`, the function `p`, and the list `xs`, just as though you'd written

```hs
not (((any''' not) p) xs)
```

What you meant to write was

```hs
all''' p xs = not (any''' (\x -> not (p x)) xs)
```

You can shorten that up a bit using the composition operator, `.`:

```hs
all''' p = not . any''' (not . p)
```

Note that if you also define `any'''` to use `all'''`, then you'll end up with an infinite loop. Perhaps you meant to define it to use an "earlier" version?